# SQL Query: First order date by customer with order great than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing the following query, but I have orders with 0 dollars that are getting grouped in with orders that have positive dollar amounts.

How do I only assign a first order date to customers, where the order has an amount greater than 0.00?

```
SELECT        HHID, MIN(ORDDATE) AS FirstOrdDate
FROM            dbo.Orders
GROUP BY HHID
```

I tried the following, but putting the amount in GROUP BY duplicates the HHID

```
SELECT        HHID, MIN(ORDDATE) AS FirstOrdDate
FROM            dbo.Orders
GROUP BY HHID, DOL
HAVING (DOL > 0.00)
```

Comment: some sample data and the expected result would help.

Comment: In order to ignore records (here all orders with a zero amount) you'd usually use a `WHERE` clause. It looks queer that you do that in `HAVING` instead. Thus you give the DBMS unnecessary work with all those zero-value records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a `WHERE` clause instead:

```
SELECT HHID, MIN(ORDDATE) AS FirstOrdDate
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE DOL > 0.00
GROUP BY HHID
```

`HAVING` happens after the aggregation, whereas `WHERE` happens before.